# No se ven mis BD

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

hola buen día mi pregunta es, porqué no puedo visualizar mis bases de datos tanto en phpmyadmin como en mysql.
 aquí en phpmyadmin no se ven

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tampoco aquí en mysql se muestran al momento de darle show databases
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en phpmyadmin si estoy logeado con root como podria hacerle 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si cuando voy a la carpeta de Mysql/data ahi estan las bases de datos que estoy buscando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Juan. Lo que yo haría: ¿Has mirado los permisos de las BBDD? root es el usuario administrador, el superusuario, es normal que las vea todas. Mira a ver que usuarios tienen las BBDD creadas y, si ves que falta el del usuario con el que te loguinas, añadelo.

Comment: la cosa es que todo lo cree desde root y pues es el unico usuario que lo tengo

Comment: ¿Tienes varias instalaciones del servidor de MySQL? Por ejemplo MySQL server que te bajas de la página de oracle, y el MySQL que te viene con XAMPP? ¿Estás seguro que el servidor que tienes arrancado es el que accede a esa carpeta donde tienes las bases de datos?

Comment: Otra pregunta más, ¿intentaste hacer una migración de otro servidor o las creaste ahí?

Comment: @viady las cree ahi.

Comment: @ordago solo tengo esa version no tengo otra